# Writing to Firebase DB using redux action writes whole new data in the DB

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I am trying to write to Firebase DB in a React application. It adds new data entry if I use DB reference and set method. However, it writes a whole new data when I use the same method through redux action.

This is the code that works.

```
      const notesRef = firebase.database().ref('notes');
      const noteRef = notesRef.child(this.state.noteId);

      const note = {
        text: this.state.text,
        timestamp: this.state.timestamp,
        title: this.titleTextArea.value,
      }

      noteRef.set(note);
```

This is the action

```
      export const addNote = (newNoteId, newNote) => async dispatch => {
            notesRef.child(newNoteId).set(newNote);
      };
```

```
      const note = {
        text: this.state.text,
        timestamp: this.state.timestamp,
        title: this.titleTextArea.value,
      }

      this.props.addNote(this.state.noteId, note);
```

Bad result:

```
notes: "a6ff48e4-f34a-483f-a639-b0dbfd703009"
```

Good result:

```
notes:
      b85def67-3877-4d2f-b5c7-23d8295768ad
            text: "{\"ops\":[{\"insert\":\"fsasfs\\n\"}]}"
            timestamp: 1557467143056
            title: "asfa"

      e4290153-a40c-464f-a92a-39eded74bd2a
            text: "{\"ops\":[{\"insert\":\"sadfasdfsd\\n\"}]}"
            timestamp: 1557467154054
            title: "asdfsdaf"
```

Comment: Where are you dispatching the action?

Comment: @RahulRana What do you mean by where?

Comment: @RahulRana Ah... I see what you meant. I had a wrong action file I thought I deleted and this file was imported in my component. It works now. Thank you!

Comment: @RahulRana Somehow, a deleted file was alive before quitting the app so I didn't get an error until Ctrl-C and re-running the app.

Comment: @RahulRana The deleted file contained notesRef.set(newNote) that is why it was setting the entire DB.

Answer (score 1):

So what 'set' function of firebase does it replace existing data with the new one. Use 'update' function to update db.

```
//get new key
var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child(newNoteId).push().key;

//Update existing
 export const addNote = (newNoteId, newNote) => async dispatch => {
    let update = {}
    update[newPostKey] = newNote
    notesRef.update(update);
 };
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with using set method here. If that's the case, it shouldn't work without redux action as well. Update method also doesn't work when using it through action.

Answer (score 1):

Basic rule is Set overrides and Update is specific to each node.  Use update instead.  You can also use push to have firebase automatically generate a unique node name:

Set:

> Using set() overwrites data at the specified location, including any
>   child nodes.

Update:

> To simultaneously write to specific children of a node without
>   overwriting other child nodes, use the update() method.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

Comment: I've tried the update method but it does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Are you sure you are updating at the correct level?  If you are updating at a higher level that incorporates other nodes it may be overriding those.

Comment: I had a deleted file that had the wrong path. But the file was still recognized by the application because I did not turn it off after deleting the file. I guess I have to restart the app whenever I delete a file just in case.